# Chrome extension permission (read data in a website)?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have built a website and a chrome extension associated with it.

I want to read all data on my website (eg. read and write cookies)

So I wrote to the manifest (let's say my website is example.com, but I also use subdomains such sub.example.com) this code

```
"permissions": [
       "http://www.example.com/",
       "cookies"
],
```

But I am worried! For example If I will need any data on `sub.example.com`, I will have to add `*.example.com` to permissions which may cause disabling extension on all computer (of course, until they approve it).

Is there any way to get permissions for all my site, including subdomains, folders, `www.example.com` and `example.com` in one line.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `*.example.com` is the way to set site-wide permissions. If there's a restriction in place for setting such permissions, it wouldn't be very effective if there were a simple way to get around it, would it?

Comment: Will `*.example.com` give me permission for example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `*.example.com/*` is the best and safest way to go. As you mentioned, the extension will be disabled but Google Chrome will pop up a notification asking for the new permissions (they'll usually click "Yes").

`*.example.com/*` covers `www.example.com` as well as `example.com`. It's basically saying "any URL on the host `example.com`.

For more info, visit the [match patterns page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).